# Связь между контейнерами Docker

Tags: docker

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в следующем:

К примеру у меня есть три контейнера. В первом контейнере крутится MySQL, во втором и третьем apache.

Вопрос заключается вот в чем как мне из каждого контейнера apache обратиться в MySQL и при этом данные этих контейнеров сохранить в разных томах (Volumes) и возможно ли для каждого контейнера с apache поставить свой пароль для БД?

Comment: Значит делайте два отдельных MySQL-контейнера, наверное? Или что вы подразумеваете под фразой "данные этих контейнеров", каких "этих"?

Comment: @andreymal получается что для каждого контейнера с apache нужно поднимать контейнер MySQL?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что хотите, чтобы у каждого MySQL был свой отдельный volume, то видимо да (но не очень понятно зачем)

Comment: @andreymal хотел в одном контейнере поднять MySQL и apache но у меня не получается запустить MySQL. В images задавал команды так 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/mysqld", "-u", "mysql"]
Но БД не запускается при этом варианте

Comment: В одном контейнере не надо, это нарушает главную суть «один контейнер — один процесс»

Comment: @andreymal вот отсюда сразу появляется вопрос как возможно запустить один контейнер с MySQL и к нему подключать контейнеры и самое главное что бы данные контейнеров которые сохраняются не как не пересекались бы между собой и желательно хранились в разных томах или если всё же возможно запустить в одном контейнере несколько сервисов таких как apache, mysql и тд

Comment: Ну значит запускать несколько контейнеров с MySQL. Не надо пытаться связывать вещи, которые не должны быть связаны